# Crontab Running script at startup

Tags: bash, cron

I have a .sh that executes a command. I want to use crontab -e and enter into the file  @reboot /path/to/command.

How do execute this in one command instead of separately running crontab -e   then manually insert the line and then saving the file.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `crontab -e` a file will be created at `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/` which its name is equal to your uesername.

So just redirect your desired line to this file:

```
echo "@reboot /path/to/file.sh" | sudo tee -a /var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USER
```

- using `tee -a` we are telling `tee` to append `@reboot /path/to/file.sh` at the end of this file instead of overwriting it.
- if it's not there it will be created.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the *right* way to do it - as explained in [How to programmatically add new crontab file without replacing previous one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/241120/65304) - is to dump the existing crontab to a temporary file, modify it, then read it back in. For example:

```
cmd='@reboot /path/to/file'
tmpfile=$(mktemp) && crontab -l > "$tmpfile"
cmd='@reboot /path/to/command'
grep -Fxq "$cmd" "$tmpfile" || echo "$cmd" >> "$tmpfile"
crontab "$tmpfile" && rm -- "$tmpfile"
```

A "quick'n'dirty" option - if you don't care about checking - would be

```
crontab -l | sed '$a@reboot /path/to/command' | crontab -
```

assuming GNU sed, which allows `a`ppend text on one line.

---

*Note: unlike writing to `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` directly, this approach doesn't need `sudo` (because `crontab` is setuid).*